# Keeping camera at player's back

Tags: c#, unity

I'm developing a 3D game similar to the Roller Ball game from Unity's tutorials mixed with a runner type game like Subway Surfers.  The game uses the arrow keys for control.  When the player hits the left or right arrow key, I want the player to do a 90 degree turn and have the camera stay behind the player.  My questions are, how would I do this?  Would I need to do this in my player controller script and just change the rotation?  Or would I need to add some controls to the camera and change the rotation of the camera every time the player hits the right or left key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/38526/smooth-follow-camera.html) has solution for your problem. Make a Camera Follow script, attach it to camera and assign `Transform` of player to it. You can further customize it according to your needs